# How to check if there are any overlays on the map?

Tags: google-maps

Is there some method in Goole Map API that allows to check whether a map has any overlays and/or markers? Something like these:

```
map.overlaysExist() // #=> true | false
// or
map.overlays()  // #=> [overlayOne, overlayTwo, ...]
```

Then it is possible to check these ways:

```
if(map.overlaysExist()) { ... do something }
// or
if((map.overlays()).length > 0) { ... do something }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())` to check if there are any markers on the map, so you could do:

```
if(map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
   //do stuff
}
```

If you just want to check that it exists at all you could just search for the specific variable you are expecting (assuming you are creating the elements as well), e.g.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
 });
```

then

```
if(marker){
   //if the Marker object exists, do something
}
```